# how to change JRadioButton selectionBall's color?

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

how to change JRadioButton selectionBall's color? we should use BasicRadioButtonUI? how should we do that? or we should change the radioButton's selectedIcon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or we should change the radioButton's selectedIcon ?

- there isn't `radioButton's selectedIcon`, everything is done in `paintIcon` (with two states)
- you can to override `paintIcon` in `BasicRadioButtonUI`

EDIT

there are two ways,

depends of Java version and used L&F, have to test

```
@Override
public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    int offset = (c.getHeight() - iconSide) / 2;
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x + offset, y + offset, dotDia, dotDia);                
}

// or

@Override
public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    int offset = (c.getHeight() - iconSide) / 2;
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRoundRect(x + offset, y + offset, dotDia, dotDia, arc, arc);
}
```

or (dirty way) to `setIcon` (prepared) in `UIManager`, required to set `revalidate()` and `repaint()` for all mouse or key events